# Unable to Recover MySQL Database [Missing FILE_CHECKPOINT]

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, recovery

Using MariaDB 10.7.3 via Homebrew on MacOS Monterey 12.6.1

While trying to recover the database after a system crash, I am stuck with the following situation.

```
[Note] mysqld (server 10.7.3-MariaDB) starting as process 41828 ...
[Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
[Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 1 !!!
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
[Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
[Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=42341,42341
[Note] InnoDB: At LSN: 44990: unable to open file ./m/#sql-alter-7a87-29.ibd for tablespace 6
[Note] InnoDB: At LSN: 46770: unable to open file ./m/#sql-backup-7a87-29.ibd for tablespace 5
    ( ... )
[Note] InnoDB: At LSN: 30937974: unable to open file ./m/#sql-alter-7a87-68.ibd for tablespace 136
[Note] InnoDB: At LSN: 31224631: unable to open file ./m/#sql-backup-7a87-68.ibd for tablespace 135
[ERROR] InnoDB: Missing FILE_CHECKPOINT at 42341 between the checkpoint 42341 and the end 35744320.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
[Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
[ERROR] Aborting
```

All my online research says to remove ib_logfile*, but I need to recover the data.

The "innodb_force_recovery" method claims to fix the situation, but only the table names are visible. Tables are not accessible and data is missing: *Error : Table doesn't exist in engine.*

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Looks like [MDEV-28976](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28976) / [MDEV-28870](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28870) and [doesn't appear to be fixable](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28870?focusedCommentId=232232&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-232232).

Comment: 6 months of work is just gone forever : \

Comment: Emphasis for those that arrive here: 3 points: a) Never remove "remove ib_logfile*". b) Deleting data is a very good way to loose it. c) Keep backups.